# How to combine two QColor objects with alpha channel?

Tags: qt, alpha

I have objects where the border color has already been determined.

Now I want the user to be able to set at least the opacity of the fill pattern. E.g., the border is blue. The user sets the opacity to 128, so the fill pattern is also drawn in blue, but half-transparent.

The next step would be to allow the user to also slightly adjust the color of the pattern. E.g.: "Use the border color, but make it half-transparent (alpha=128) and a little bit yellow-ish.".

Is there a (useful) way to combine two colors where one does not have an alpha value set? Or would it make more sense to set an alpha value on the original color and combine it with an "overlay color" that also has an alpha value set?

And is there a function (or otherwise, can someone give a short code snippet) to combine the two QColor objects?

Comment: I stumbled over the mentioning of the XRender extension in the Qt documentation. Wikipedia said it uses http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alpha_compositing. So I am now reading that article.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would look at existing color pickers that are out there (Gimp, Photoshop, Paint, [wwWidgets](https://github.com/TheDZhon/wwwidgets)).  Most of them deal with a few different ways of picking your color:

Saturation, Hue, Value, Brightness, Contrast, RGB, CMYK, HSV, Alpha/Opacity.

Qt handles a bunch of these right out of the box:

[QColor](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qcolor.html#details)

In order to combine two colors, I would probably average their different components together:

```
// Rough pseudocode

Color1 RGBA, Color 2 RGBA, Color 3 = combination

Color3.R = (Color1.R + Color2.R)/2
Color3.G = (Color1.G + Color2.G)/2
Color3.B = (Color1.B + Color2.B)/2
Color3.A = (Color1.A + Color2.A)/2
```

I hope that helps.

PS: Understanding [Color Space](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Color_space) can be helpful, too.

Comment: just averaging the alpha channel instead of weighting the colors with them seems as good as ignoring the alpha in general.

Comment: @IARI: may seem so, buit GLSL mix command doesn't do anything else...

Comment: I'm not a Shader expert but don't think it makes so much sense to look at something like just the mix command in isolation - The question is what behaviour the user (/dev) expects.

If you overlay two colors (images) with regular blending, mixing the color red(100%alpha) with a 100% clear (black 0% alpha) should definitely result in just red 
- not red mixed with black and not something with a 50% alpha.

Answer (score 1):

This problem has led me to code this in the past (Qt/C++):

```
template < typename T >
// Operator to mix two QColors -> lerp
QRgba64 mix( const QColor& q0, const QColor& q1, const T mix )
{
    static const auto shuf{ _mm_set1_epi64x( 0x0d0c090805040100 ) };
    auto              t{ _mm_set1_ps( static_cast< float >( mix ) ) };
    auto              a{ _mm_cvtepi32_ps( _mm_cvtepu16_epi32( _mm_cvtsi64_si128( q0.rgba64() ) ) ) };
    auto              b{ _mm_cvtepi32_ps( _mm_cvtepu16_epi32( _mm_cvtsi64_si128( q1.rgba64() ) ) ) };
    return qRgba64( _mm_cvtsi128_si64(
        _mm_shuffle_epi8( _mm_cvtps_epi32( _mm_fmadd_ps( t, b, _mm_fnmadd_ps( t, a, a ) ) ), shuf ) ) );
}
```

It's the simplest possible parallel "mix" (aka. LERP) implementation in SSE4.2/AVX[FMA].  Should run on all computers of the last 8 years.  Only older ones missing the FMA-CPUID need a different implementation:

```
return QRgba64( _mm_cvtsi128_si64( _mm_shuffle_epi( _mm_cvtps_epi32( 
       _mm_add_ps( a, _mm_mul_ps( t, _mm_sub_ps( b, a ) ) ), shuf ) ) );
```

Please bear in mind that the last line doesn't always reach b for t==1.0 because of IEEE 754 rounding (Ryg explained it well, see the link below).

Further reading: https://fgiesen.wordpress.com/2012/08/15/linear-interpolation-past-present-and-future/

P.S.: as `uint16` (QRgba64) or even `uint8` (QRgba) are used, we could also implement it all in integer-SSE.